# Get href from link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to print the relative URL from the href shown below in the console:

```
<div class="span-8 last">
  <span class="large">
    <a href="/property/3938749">1221 Pearl St.</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

using the following jQuery call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".span-8 .large").hover(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(href);
});
```

which I believe is essentially what was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508021/how-to-get-the-clicked-links-href-with-jquery), but when I hover over the selected element, instead of

> /property/3938749

the console is showing me

> undefined

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: @ProllyGeek Not a duplicate.  This at best a typo-like question, in that the OP is attempting to get an attribute on the wrong element.

Comment: @Daedalus i was in hurry so made that from mobile , you are totally right though , so experience on mobile really sucks.

Comment: @Daedalus Doh, you're right. I'm _very_ new to jquery and I got confused about what element I was trying to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".span-8 .large").hover(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    console.log(href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span-8 last">
  <span class="large">
    <a href="/property/3938749">1221 Pearl St.</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".span-8 .large").hover(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
    console.log(href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span-8 last">
  <span class="large">
    <a href="/property/3938749">1221 Pearl St.</a>
 </span>
</div>
```

You need to get the anchor so select the anchor by `.find('a')`