# How to detect the name extension in the link clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hyperlink

I know how to create modal windows but I cannot find a solution to detect the name extension in the address of the link clicked by the user to then display a modal form.

I need to show the modal window only when a link containing the .MP3 / .AVI name extension is clicked.

```
<table id="list">
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.avi">video file.avi</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.txt">text file.txt</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.pdf">pdf file.pdf</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.mp3">video file.mp3</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the clicked link's href with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508021/how-to-get-the-clicked-links-href-with-jquery)

Comment: No, I need to show the modal window only when a link containing the .MP3 / .AVI name extension is clicked. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Split your href value when click , get file extension and do whatever you want .  (".link a").click(function() { var herf = $(this).attr("href"); var ext = herf.split('.')[1]; alert(ext);    });

Comment: Thanks "Shree", I passed by .split in the documentation. thanks too "showdev".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved, here is the solution:** show the modal window only when a link containing the .txt, .pdf, .jpg, name extension is clicked.

Links without extension are also included except those ending in a slash, if you want not to include them replace the pattern with this:

`/^(.(?!.*\.txt|.*\.pdf|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg|.*\.png))*$/`

```js
$('.link a').each(function(){

    // modal login for documents, images and files without extension
    var herf = $(this).attr("href");     
    if(herf.match(/^(.(?!.*\.txt|.*\.pdf|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg|.*\.png|.*\/))*$/)) {
        $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle', 'modal').attr('data-bs-target', '#exampleModal');
    }
});
```

```html
<table id="list">
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.avi">avi file</a> deny</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.txt">txt file </a> allow</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.mp3">mp3 file </a> deny</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file.jpg">jpg file</a> allow</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="file">empty file</a> deny</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="dir/">directory/</a> allow</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text()` in jquery.

```js
    $('.link a').click(function(){
        var link = $(this).text();
        $("#write").text(link)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list">
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">video file.avi</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">text file.txt</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">pdf file.pdf</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">video file.mp3</a></td></tr>
</table>
<p id="write"></p>
```